# R: How to improve the mean calculation in image matrix variable in R?

Tags: r, image, png, mean

Here is my problem in R...

I am using library: png for reading *.png file into variable

```
imgIn = readPNG('image.png');
```

I have a data.frame that store the x, y value of image. X, y are just like (1,1) (1,2) (1,3). X, Y are in range of the image dimension.

```
> head(df)
  x y 
  8 8 
  9 8 
 10 8 
 11 8 
 12 8 
 13 8
```

Below is the code to get mean of all points in 3x3 square that x,y are the center of that square

```
  m = apply(df, 1, function(row){
    x = as.integer(row['x']) - 1
    y = as.integer(row['y']) - 1
    mean(imgIn[y:3, x:3, 1])
  });
```

The code run really really SLOW (about 5 min) with the dimension of image is 512x477

My question is how to improve the code above ??

Thanks in advance !